# Is it possible to write ARRAYFORMULA of another ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, lookup, array-formulas

I'm trying to do the following:

[image: Problem Screen Shot]

- If ID is unique, then showing nothing in the "Result" column
- But, if the ID is not unique, then write all the Items for that ID separated by a comma (,)
- This condition will check for the range of row-1 t the current row. Not considered for the below row
- You can check the item for ID 1 as an example

I'm using the formula to solve this problem. To do that, I need to write the formula in each cell. But I want to solve this using the ARRAYFORMULA so I can write the formula in the 1st cell.

This is what I am using right now:

> =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2=$B$1:F1,$C$1:C1,"")))

You can see the file here: [Check this file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V33NlGzK40wX-wwJKyJVocSMs_ChPBmv3j7arpfucuk/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance for your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))>1, 
 REGEXEXTRACT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"", 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&"×", SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " ", "_"), ROW(B2:B)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×")), 2, 0)), 
 TRIM(REPT("[\w]+ ", COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))))), ), " ", ", "), "_", " "))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please check this file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A-AFXvd8hYwy7c9s5ABIXN0ARRAP89igDukz33OGiVA/edit#gid=1598646108

I use this formula in "Y2" but get an error "#VALUE!". My expected result is in column "Z".

Comment: @AmirHossain see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzD4m.png

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance. But I am facing this yet. You can see this in the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A-AFXvd8hYwy7c9s5ABIXN0ARRAP89igDukz33OGiVA/edit

When the product column has the special character "-", then the formula not return the correct result.

Comment: @AmirHossain change `"[\w]+ "` to `"[\w-]+ "`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `REGEXREPLACE()`:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B,IF(VLOOKUP(B2:B,B:C,2,0)=C2:C,"",REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",1,B2:B&"&"&C2:C),"\b(?:"&B2:B&"&"&C2:C&"\b.*|"&B2:B&"&([^,]+,)|.)","$1")&C2:C),""))
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. The formula works perfectly fine. But this formula do freeze the page sometime. I don't know why, but it slowdown my page. Otherwise, this was an excellent job.